# Given prime $p$ and $r, s > 0$ such that $\sum_{i = 1}^p\frac{1}{i} = \frac{r}{ps}$. Prove that $p^3 \mid r - s$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Given prime $p > 3$ and positives $r$ and $s$ such that $1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{p - 1} + \dfrac{1}{p} = \dfrac{r}{ps}$. Prove that $p^3 \mid r - s$.

We have that $$1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{p - 1} + \dfrac{1}{p} = \dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{j = 1}^p\prod_{i \ne j}i}{\displaystyle \prod_{i = 1}^pi} \implies \left\{ \begin{align} r = \sum_{j = 1}^p\prod_{i \ne j}i\\ s = \prod_{i = 1}^{p - 1}i \end{align} \right. \ (i = \overline{1, p})$$

$$ \implies r - s = \sum_{j = 1}^{p - 1}\prod_{i \ne j}i \ (i = \overline{1, p})$$

Let $p - 1 = p'$, it can be seen that $p \mid r - s$, we have that $\displaystyle \dfrac{r - s}{p} = \sum_{j = 1}^{p'}\prod_{i \ne j}i$ $(i = \overline{1, p'})$

$$ = p\sum_{j = 1}^{q - 1}\prod_{i \ne q \pm j}i \ \left(i = \overline{1, p'}, q = \frac{p'}{2}\right)$$

Again, it can be seen that $p \mid \dfrac{r - s}{p}$, then I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Wolstenholme's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme's_theorem), there are $m,n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ such that $\gcd(p,n)=1$ and
$$1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{p - 1}=\frac{p^2m}{n}.$$
Then
$$\frac{p^2m}{n}+\frac{1}{p} = \dfrac{r}{ps}\implies
\frac{p^3m+n}{pn}=\dfrac{r}{ps}\implies p^3sm=n(r-s)$$
and we may conclude that $p^3$ divides $r-s$.

P.S. For a proof of Wolstenholme's theorem I recommend this [note](https://www.math.uci.edu/~tchoi/notes/wolstenholme.pdf) by Timothy H. Choi.

Comment: @Lê Thành Đạt Are you still interested in your question? Any further doubt? Any feedback?

Comment: Right, I'm sorry for the five-month late response, thanks for the solution, I had to re-read about the theorem a couple of times, but other than that, it's quite straightforward.